# list numbering get reset after sections

Tags: restructuredtext

Why is the third `#.` not a `3` and how is possible to continues numbering?

```
============
Part title..
============
#. sss
#. ddd

***************
Chapter title..
***************
#.
```

Comment: To me it makes sense that numbered lists are "section-local". You have two separate lists, not a single list that spans more than one section. I guess that it might be possible to have some markup that says "continue numbering from previous numbered list". But that is not part of reST today and just a speculation on my part.